# replacing argument values with return values

Tags: python, list, return-value, maya

I'm creating a list of selected objects in maya for an IK/FKswitch and have run into a bit of a problem.

When I create my selection list instances I need to temporarily make my argument values foo, bar, and baz.

When I select my control curves in maya, I want the values to change from foo, bar, and baz to the control curves I selected.

I was under the impression that when I return the variables from my selectjoints_... functions that I could achieve this change. However, when I print my list I just see foo, bar, & baz and I don'treally understand why

```
class Create_Selection_Chains:

    def __init__(self, name, Fks, Ikw, ikpv):
        self.name = name
        self.Fks = Fks
        self.Ikw = Ikw
        self.ikpv = ikpv

    def select_joints_afk(self):

        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):
            sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
            fks = sel
            fkCtrls = cmds.listRelatives(sel,  type=("transform",'nurbsCurve'))
            Fks = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in fkCtrls if nurbsCurve.startswith('FK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(gtF0, edit = True, tx ='' .join(sel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
            Fks.extend(sel)
            print Fks
            return Fks 
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], 
                                        defaultButton='Ok', dismissString='No' )

    def select_joints_aikw(self):
        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):

            sel=cmds.ls(selection = True)
            ikwrist = sel
            Ikw = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in ikwrist if nurbsCurve.startswith('IK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(gtF1, edit = True, tx ='' .join(ikwrist),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
            cmds.select(ikwrist)
            print Ikw
            return Ikw
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], defaultButton='Ok', 
                                        dismissString='No' )

    def select_joints_ikpv(self):

        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):
            sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
            ikPvsel = sel
            ikpv = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in ikPvsel if nurbsCurve.startswith('IK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(gtF2, edit = True, tx ='' .join(ikPvsel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))        
            cmds.select(ikPvsel)
            print ikpv
            return ikpv
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], 
                                        defaultButton='Ok', dismissString='No' )
```

One of my selection instances:

```
right_arm_select = Create_Selection_Chains("right arm", "foo", "bar", "baz")
```

The button I press to print my list
:

```
cmds.button(label='IK 2 FK', command = 'ik_2_fk()', width=100)
```

code for printing the list

```
    def ik_2_fk(self):
        print("List created" + self.Fks +self.Ikw+self.ikpv)
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to do `self.Ikw = ` and not `Ikw =`?  Currently the name of that variable does not matter at all, since it is contained in your function.  The only way for that value to make that change is if the return is used elsewhere. I know you might not be sure yourself, but the flow is not clear without maya knowledge.

Comment: O crap you are absolutely right! Changing it worked.